# web service security con php, mysql, xml

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy intentando hacer un servicio web SOAP con seguridad pero no logro establecer una buena seguridad aca tengo el ejemplo de lo que hago:

```
public function Seguridad($variablesSeguridad){
         $usuario='pagosyre';
         $password='ladrones';

         $token_servidor = "pyr";
         $token = $variablesSeguridad->UsernameToken->Id;
         $tokenUsuario = $variablesSeguridad->UsernameToken->Username->Id;
         $user = $variablesSeguridad->UsernameToken->Username->_;

         $token_clave = $variablesSeguridad->Password->Id;
         $pass_type = $variablesSeguridad->Password->Type;
         $pass = $variablesSeguridad->Password->_;


         if($token == $token_servidor && $tokenUsuario == $token_servidor . "@usuario" && $user == $usuario && $token_clave == $token_servidor . "@password" && $pass == $password && $pass_type!='')
         {

             $this->verificacion = true;
         }else{

             $this->verificacion = false;
         }
     }
//Ejemplo
     public function MiMetodo($variable){

         $fecha = date ("F j. Y. g:i:s a");

         $datos = $variable->mensaje. " " . $fecha;

         $Mi_arreglo=array(

             "validacion_usuario"=>($this->verificacion==false)?"Error Login":"Exito Login",
             "out"=>$datos,
         );


         return $Mi_arreglo;

     }
```

Cuando voy a consumir el servicio en SoapUI aunque coloques en error el usuario o la password igual te da el resultado y eso no deberia ser asi...

Quiero implentar que el usuario y la pass y salgan de la base de datos y se reciba un token.

Si me podrían ayudar seria magnifico, soy muy nueva en esto!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nunca debes usar == para la comparación de cadenas. 
Prueba tu código cambiando el == por ===

```
    if($token === $token_servidor && $tokenUsuario === $token_servidor . "@usuario" && $user === $usuario && $token_clave === $token_servidor . "@password" && $pass === $password && $pass_type!='')
    {
        $this->verificacion = true;
    } else {
        $this->verificacion = false;
    }
```

Comment: Prueba con comparaciones como '1e4' == '10000'. O alguna comparación con el valor 0 por ejemplo 0 == 'asdasd lo que quieras 123'. El resultado será siempre true

Comment: Aunque le coloques los "===" y coloque id, user y pass errados me sigue mostrando la hora cosa que no debería hacer!

Comment: @AndreaValentina según tu código es irrelevante si la verificación pasa o es errada para mostrar la fecha. Es relevante solo para mostrar un mensaje asociado a "validacion_usuario".